# Replacing the test with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace the text using the sed, but it's showing some error. Not getting where I'm getting wrong.

```
sed -i 's/process.env.REDIRECT_URI/http:\/\/test-domain.apps.io/\callback/g' input.txt
```

Have this :

```
process.env.REDIRECT_URI
```

Replace this with :

```
http://test-domain.apps.io
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed -i 's/process.env.REDIRECT_URI/http:\/\/test-domain.apps.io/g' input.txt
```

Notes:

1. The original command has a spurious string `/\callback`.  All that was needed to make the code work was to remove it.
2. `.` is a wildcard.  If you want to be sure that you are matching periods, they should be escaped:

   ```
   sed -i 's/process\.env\.REDIRECT_URI/http:\/\/test-domain.apps.io/g' input.txt
   ```
3. Sometimes, its clearer if one doesn't have to escape `/`.  One can use a separator of one's choice.  For example, use `@`:

   ```
   sed -i 's@process\.env\.REDIRECT_URI@http://test-domain.apps.io@g' input.txt
   ```
4. If you did want `/callback` in the output, use:

   ```
   sed -i 's/process\.env\.REDIRECT_URI/http:\/\/test-domain.apps.io\/callback/g' input.txt
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sed -i 's@process\.env\.REDIRECT_URI@http://test-domain.apps.io/callback@g' input.txt
   ```

Comment: Are you sure you need to escape `/`.  This works fine: `'s@process\.env\.REDIRECT_URI@http://test-domain.apps.io@g'`

Comment: @Jotne Thanks for catching that typo.  (As you know, the whole point of `@` was to avoid escaping `/`.)  Answer corrected.